# Manipulação de arquivos MP3

Tags: áudio

Gostaria de saber o que devo pesquisar/estudar para manipular um arquivo MP3, desde a sua leitura até alteração e exibição;

Algumas dúvidas pontuais seriam:

- Existe alguma linguagem mais apropriada para este tipo de uso, se sim, qual?
- Dentro das linguagens em que é possível trabalhar com isso, é feito de forma mais abstrata ou é executado com o auxílio de bibliotecas?
- Para a identificação de padrões na leitura, qual seria a ferramenta mais adequada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta certamente será fechada rsrs

Eu sou o Rei em responder perguntas que são fechadas kkkk

Rapaz a Decodificação de arquivos `mp3` é muiiiiitooo complexo, esse processo dá um `TCC` de peso...

Eu não sei e não entendi o tipo de manipulação que deseja fazer, mas para manipular (aumentar volume, aplicar filtros, alterar frequência, alterar velocidade, inverter áudio, mover o áudio para tocar em determinado segundo ou minuto, etc) não tem escapatória, vc vai ter que decodificar para ter os dados em formato [PCM](http://ptcomputador.com/P/computer-programming-languages/86481.html)

Certamente você vai ter que usar alguma lib pronta para executar a decodificação, existem algumas `LibMad, AMP, LAME, MPG123` todas elas estão escritas em `C` para python27 eu conheço o `pymedia` exemplo de uso nessa minha [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171169/how-to-play-mp3-from-url/38247503), para java tem o [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html), a grande maioria delas são algum tipo de fork das libs escritas em `C`.

A lib que eu considero mais simples de entender é a lib `AMP`, até onde sei foi a primeira lib(free) que surgiu na net capaz de decodificar arquivos mp3, foi dela que surgiu o WinAMP, algumas empresas usaram essa lib dentro de sistemas embarcados (mp3 players), não é muito fácil achar os fontes dessa lib, talvez na deepweb, eu deva ter em algum CD da década de 90 huahuahua...

Comment: Muito obrigado, me deu uma série de diretrizes necessárias, no caso o que vou fazer com esse arquivo vai ser identificação de padrões de ondas sonoras.
Mais uma vez muito obrigado.